# Angular TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined

Tags: angular, nrwl

Just creating component in Angular and getting the following error, I think Angular mismatch version is a warning not an error, I also tried and removed package-lock.json and node_modules too.

```
    λ ng g component  libs\layout\src\lib\features\footer
    Your global Angular CLI version (11.2.6) is greater than your local version (11.0.7). The local Angular CLI version is used.   

    To disable this warning use "ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch false".
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined
        at noCacheNormalize (...\nrwl\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\src\virtual-fs\path.js:207:14)
        at Object.normalize (...\nrwl\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\src\virtual-fs\path.js:189:21)
        at Object.parseName (...\nrwl\node_modules\@nrwl\angular\node_modules\@schematics\angular\utility\parse-name.js:15:56)
        at ...\nrwl\node_modules\@nrwl\angular\node_modules\@schematics\angular\component\index.js:96:41
    Cannot read property 'match' of undefined
```

Comment: what is your npm verison also your cli version

Comment: CLI: 11.2.6, NPM:7.6.1